# EXT JS store.loadData() is not appending the data

Tags: extjs

I am trying to use `store.loadData(data, true)` to append data to an existing store but for some reason it is clearing the store and replacing it with the new data which should only happen if the boolean is set to false which it is not. Is there something I am missing that I need to do to make sure the data is appended to the old data and not replacing it entirely?

Edit Additional code. Currently I am pulling a row from a grid and creating a new window with additional information for that object that is pulled from a database. The idea is that all the possible data for the rows is stored in one store and then when the window appears the store has a filter added so that you only see data that pertains to that particular object. At some point I iterate every single object in the grid and check to see if it has data that was edited. Which is an issue if I only have data from the last object that was edited.

```
editSelectedNode: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex){
    var store = Ext.getStore('EditStore');
    var win = Ext.create('BOMGeneratorSencha.view.EditMenu', {});
    var item = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).get('original'); 
    console.debug(item);
    win.show();
    var el = win.getEl();
    store.clearFilter(true);
    console.debug(store.getCount());
    if(store.getCount() == 0){
    el.mask('Loading Values');
    console.debug(store.getCount());
    Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : 'EditPart.jsp',   
            timeout: 300000,
            params : {
            item: item
            },
            success: function (response, opt) {
                el.unmask();
                var res = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                if (res.success) {              
                    console.debug(res.results);
                    store.loadData(res.results,true);
                    console.debug(store);
                }
                else {
                    console.debug("JSON failure");
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Invalid part number');
                }               
            },
            failure: function(response,options){
                console.debug("major failure");
                el.unmask();
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Connection failed<br>' + response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing some code that we can examine, there's probably something else going on. You need to isolate the problem. If you can reproduce it at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle, then it'd much easier to help

Answer (score 0):

I have a code that is similat to your one. But when i get response, I dont use

```
store.loadData(someData)
```

instead I am using following steps to load data(piece of my code placed here):

```
success: function(response, opts){
    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText)
        ,data = obj.data
        ,$ = Ext.ComponentQuery;

    var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.SomeStore',{
        data : data 
    });
    $.query('SomeGrid')[0].bindStore(store);
    $.query('SomeGrid')[0].refresh();
}
```

Comment: in other words, i create a store from data which was returned by server, and then i bind this store to corresponding panel or grid.

Comment: Unfortunately my issue is that I have an already existing store that is attached to a grid that when I try to add additional data to it erases the old data rather than appending to it.